# Why can't I remap keys?

Tags: brutal-legend

I am playing Brutal Legend through Steam and have just killed the fist Nun, very beginning of the game before getting the car or leaving the very first are.

I decided I want to change the lock-on button from ctrl to a thumb button on my mouse.  I hit ESC, go to the keymaping area of the menu, and click the activity I want to re-map.

A nice box pups up telling me to "Press any key or mouse".  I click the thuhmb mouse button I want to map to.  Nothing happens.  I try again.  Still nothing.  I try middle mouse button.  Nothing.  I have not pushed every letter on my keyboard as well as ctrl and a few other keys, but nothing changes.  I still see the pop-up message.

Maybe it froze, I think to myself.  I check task manager and it says it is Running, no issues at all.  I open steam overlay, works fine.  I try ESC to get out of the menu, still nothing.

So now I have tried mapping this to anything, including what it was, as well as trying to get out of the menu withough closing the game completely.  Nothing is working.  Any ideas on how I can re-map this or beck out of this menu without closing the game completely?

Here is the screen I am stuck at.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to get out of this while remaining in the game.

The good news is that the game did not crash, and therefore has a recent auto-save.  Close the game (Alt+F4) and re-start it.  For this case, the auto-save is right before the battle with the nun.

This may be an issue with remapping keys while in the game as you can map to mouse-4 and mouse-5, not sure about higher numbers, from the main menu (prior to entering "New Game" or "Continue".